# Karate tests execution

Tags: jenkins, karate

Our requirement for API testing is:

1. To deploy test-automation module (Karate feature files, custom java classes) into AWS ECS-Fargate cluster.
2. Trigger the tests via Jenkins pipeline after every build of the actual microservice.
3. In addition to above, test-automation module should be triggered to run test suite on-demand and/or at scheduled intervals (say nightly) and send reports.

I have gone through Karate Distributed Testing and stand-alone executable jar options, but doesn't seem suitable for my case. Is Distributed Testing supported only for "Web-UI" automation testing?

Any thoughts would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this use-case, just use a Maven + JUnit project and then there is no difference between Karate and any other Jenkins Java pipeline.

It should be Jenkin's responsibility to do a scheduled build. It is up to you how to get all this into Fargate, maybe building a Docker container is part of the answer, but I would recommend trying to keep it simple.

Here is some Docker related discussion that may help: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/396

Open a new question with *specifics* next time.